# facebook connect - can't login in using ie - permission denied

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm having some issues using Internet Explorer when trying to login into my facebook app. I'm using facebook connect.

I'm using some standard facebook connect code, which you can see here - http://jsfiddle.net/M74qN/

I'm having two issues - a javascript error -

```
Line: 23
Char: 3884
Error: Premission denied
Code: 0
URL: MYDEVELOPMENTSITE.LOCAL
```

And a facebook error -

```
An error occurred with my-facebook-app. Please try again later.
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: redirect_uri URL is not properly formatted
```

The login works in FF & chrome.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

Edit - This may be something to do with it - http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19042

Although, if it was effecting the implementation of **ALL** facebook connect usage on IE, I presume there would be a lot more information/complaints on t'interweb.

Also, I do get a similar error on Hulu, but it still lets me authorise the app, which I can't do with mine.

---

**EDIT 2** -  After clearing cookies and looking again - the facebook error is changing to

```
Invalid Argument
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.
```

The address of that page is -

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=MYAPIKEY&skip_api_login=1&display=popup&cancel_url=null%3Ffb_xd_fragment%23%3F%3D%26cb%3Df29536d8cef9e1c%26relation%3Dopener%26transport%3Dfragment%26frame%3Df3208481ca1f38c%26result%3D%2522xxRESULTTOKENxx%2522&fbconnect=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%MYAPIKEY%26redirect_uri%3Dnull%253Ffb_xd_fragment%2523%253F%253D%2526cb%253Df29536d8cef9e1c%2526relation%253Dopener%2526transport%253Dfragment%2526frame%253Df3208481ca1f38c%2526result%253D%252522xxRESULTTOKENxx%252522%26sdk%3Djoey%26display%3Dpopup%26api_key%MYAPIKEY%26fbconnect%3D1%26locale%3Den_US%26return_session%3D1%26session_version%3D3%26from_login%3D1&rcount=1

I'm thinking it must be something to with this  - redirect_uri%3Dnull in the url params.

But I've no idea how to change that, and also am bewildered as to why it's an ie only issue.

As an aside, it must be said that the Facebook developer forums are truly awful.

Comment: +1 nice question - I see no problem in your code

Comment: Are you using localhost as domain in the URL? I had a similar issue with IE when that was the case. To resolve the issue I added an entry to my local hosts file to create a non-"localhost" domain.

Comment: The dev site is mapped to http://client-name.local/ I'll try changing it to http://client-name.somethingelse and see what happens.

Comment: I've just tried with client-name.test and am still getting the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied error in all.js](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7280007/permission-denied-error-in-all-js)

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get it working by adding a Custom Channel URL, as per this page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

Seemed to work, but I'm still not sure why I had the error in the first place so I'm going to leave the question open for the moment to see if anyone can give a better answer.

Comment: Funny, I was having the same problem and *removing* the custom channel url fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely coming up because you have configured your Facebook Developers account to point to a specific URL on the web, and you are developing locally - meaning the URL that Facebook looks for is `www.mydomain.com`, however you are running on a local test server (most likely), so it's only finding `localhost:7689//` (just an example).

There's ways around this, but in my experience, I've just deployed a hidden subdomain (or password protected one), to the ACTUAL domain, and tested it there, and then move the code over to your regular domain once it works.

Comment: That's not it, or at last I'm nearly certain it's not. I can log in using Firefox or chrome so It's specifically an IE bug. I can't imagine that the app settings would be read differently by the three browsers. (although I have no proof for this).

Comment: Hm, can we see where you input the facebook scripts and how you define the fbml elements/

Comment: All I can show you at the mo is what's in the fiddle, linked above - http://jsfiddle.net/M74qN/ it's a bit of a stripped down version of what I'm actually using, but it may help. Otherwise I'm back in the office tmo morning. Thanks for your help.